# CSS hover not working with jQuery

Tags: html, css

This social media footer downloaded from codepen working perfect on its own. When applied on jQuery page hover effect is not working at all.

Below you can view my code, I wish to make hover property of social buttons to become visible again. `!important;` property found in other posts here also not working.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").hover(function() {
    $(".content").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + $(this).data("bind")).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.p{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.content {
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s all linear;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: -2px;
    }
.content.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

#content1 {
 background-image: url(file:///C|/Users/kaf/Desktop/My%20ultimate%20site/38e23136-b943-4487-930c-f4d7a50fccce.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
.button {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
 font-size:24px;
 color:#FFF;
 margin: 10px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    cursor: pointer;
} 
.footer {
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.social {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-family: Entypo;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: color .3s;}
 .social:hover {
 color: #000 !important;
 cursor:pointer; 
}

  .social {
  box-shadow: rgb(210, 210, 210) 1px 1px,
    rgb(210, 210, 210) 2px 2px,
    rgb(211, 211, 211) 3px 3px,
    rgb(211, 211, 211) 4px 4px,
    rgb(211, 211, 211) 5px 5px,
    rgb(212, 212, 212) 6px 6px,
    rgb(212, 212, 212) 7px 7px,
    rgb(212, 212, 212) 8px 8px,
    rgb(213, 213, 213) 9px 9px,
    rgb(213, 213, 213) 10px 10px,
    rgb(214, 214, 214) 11px 11px,
    rgb(214, 214, 214) 12px 12px,
    rgb(214, 214, 214) 13px 13px,
    rgb(215, 215, 215) 14px 14px,
    rgb(215, 215, 215) 15px 15px,
    rgb(215, 215, 215) 16px 16px,
    rgb(216, 216, 216) 17px 17px,
    rgb(216, 216, 216) 18px 18px,
    rgb(216, 216, 216) 19px 19px,
    rgb(217, 217, 217) 20px 20px,
    rgb(217, 217, 217) 21px 21px,
    rgb(218, 218, 218) 22px 22px,
    rgb(218, 218, 218) 23px 23px,
    rgb(218, 218, 218) 24px 24px,
    rgb(219, 219, 219) 25px 25px,
    rgb(219, 219, 219) 26px 26px,
    rgb(219, 219, 219) 27px 27px,
    rgb(220, 220, 220) 28px 28px,
    rgb(220, 220, 220) 29px 29px,
    rgb(221, 221, 221) 30px 30px;
   text-shadow: rgb(226, 226, 226) 1px 1px,
    rgb(227, 227, 227) 2px 2px,
    rgb(227, 227, 227) 3px 3px,
    rgb(228, 228, 228) 4px 4px,
    rgb(229, 229, 229) 5px 5px,
    rgb(229, 229, 229) 6px 6px,
    rgb(230, 230, 230) 7px 7px,
    rgb(230, 230, 230) 8px 8px,
    rgb(231, 231, 231) 9px 9px,
    rgb(232, 232, 232) 10px 10px,
    rgb(232, 232, 232) 11px 11px,
    rgb(233, 233, 233) 12px 12px,
    rgb(233, 233, 233) 13px 13px,
    rgb(234, 234, 234) 14px 14px,
    rgb(235, 235, 235) 15px 15px,
    rgb(235, 235, 235) 16px 16px,
    rgb(236, 236, 236) 17px 17px,
    rgb(236, 236, 236) 18px 18px,
    rgb(237, 237, 237) 19px 19px,
    rgb(238, 238, 238) 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
html >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alfandari&co</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css"> 
    
</head>
 <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300');
@import url('http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo');
    
      </style>
<body>
<div id="content1" class="content active">
<div class="container" align="center">
<button class="button buttonx" data-bind="content1">OUR COMPANY</button>
<button class="button buttonx" data-bind="content2">OUR HISTORY</button>
<button class="button buttonx" data-bind="content3">UNIQUE PIECES</button>
<button class="button buttonx" data-bind="content4">JEWELRY</button>
<button class="button buttonx" data-bind="content5">CONTACT US</button>
</div>
  <p>Page 1</p>
 
  <div class="footer">
  <div class="social">&#62220;</div>
  <div class="social">&#62217;</div>
  <div class="social">&#127916;</div>
 <div class="social">&#128247;</div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

**Just used this code:**

```
$(function() {
  $("button").hover(function() {
    $(".content").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately still not working...Hover property in social buttoons seemms frozen

Comment: see the preview link, Hover on top menu, you will understand what i did for you.
But now it's seems to be you want something else. 
_Will you please clarify what do you want when social buttons hover?_